# Is Google analytics tracking all of my traffic? on all accessible variations/properties

Tags: google-analytics, https, subdomain, http, no-www

*I am wondering is Google analytics track all of my properties?*

- `https://www.example.com` (SSL + www)
- `https://example.com` (SSL - www)
- `http://www.example.com` (Non-SSL + WWW)
- `http://example.com` (Non-SSL - www)

*Example of the GA tracking code I am using:*

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
  ga('create', 'UA-1234567891-0', { 'cookieDomain': 'example.com' } );
  // Plugins
  ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');ga('require', 'outboundLinkTracker');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the same tracking code is embedded on all these URLs - yes. 
It should set cookies on all subdomains.
Regardless if SSL or Non-SSL.

But i would suggest not to use a specific cookie domain if not reeeeally necessary. And it looks like "not necessary" in your case :-)

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
  ga('create', 'UA-1234567891-0', 'auto');
  // Plugins
  ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');ga('require', 'outboundLinkTracker');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: If you don't specify the cookie domain there can be problems when users visit first `www.example.com` and then `example.com`.   by default Google will use `www.example.com` as the cookie domain for the first, then those cookies won't be visible to the second.   Putting your registered domain name in as the cookie domain is good practice for GA.   That way all subdomains (including www) will be able to share users.   See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id for the documentation about how GA set the domain by default.